# Clojurescript/Reagent handling errors

Tags: error-handling, clojurescript, om, reagent

We are starting to use Clojuescript/Reagent for our next development phase of our product. Basically we need a way, to do a single operation on the atom and we came up with a method like:
    (def app-state (r/atom {}))

```
(defn select [index]
    (swap! app-state
       #(-> %
            (assoc-in [:storyboard :pages 0 :layers 0 :children 0 :is_selected] true)
            (assoc-in (GET ....)) ;; ajax call
            (assoc-in [:selected :selected_tab] "tab_properties")
            (assoc-in [:selected :page_object_cursor] [0])
         )))
```

Basically the swap gets a function where all needed operations are chained. It is brilliant. However, I am looking at ways to handle errors. I would like to have a separate atom for errors:

```
(def errors (r/atom []))
```

and when an error occurs, to capture it and add it to the errors, without having the app-state swapped (the application remains in the last stable state). So we use throw from the chain and a try cactch

```
(defn change-title [title]
  (try
    (swap! app-state
       #(-> %
            (assoc :text title)
            ((fn [state] 
               (throw "there is an error")))
            ))
    (catch js/Object e
      (swap! errors conj e))))
```

So I would expect the error to be caught, and @errors to have it. But the reality is:

***Uncaught there is an error**

weather_app$core$change_title @ core.cljs?rel=1450266738018:59(anonymous function) @ core.cljs?rel=1450266738018:108executeDispatch @ react-with-addons.inc.js:3311SimpleEventPlugin.executeDispatch @ react-with-addons.inc.js:17428forEachEventDispatch @ react-with-addons.inc.js:3299executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-with-addons.inc.js:3320executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-with-addons.inc.js:2693forEachAccumulated @ react-with-addons.inc.js:19430EventPluginHub.processEventQueue @ react-with-addons.inc.js:2900runEventQueueInBatch @ react-with-addons.inc.js:11217ReactEventEmitterMixin.handleTopLevel @ react-with-addons.inc.js:11243handleTopLevelImpl @ react-with-addons.inc.js:11329Mixin.perform @ react-with-addons.inc.js:18402ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates @ react-with-addons.inc.js:9669batchedUpdates @ react-with-addons.inc.js:16633ReactEventListener.dispatchEvent @ react-with-addons.inc.js:11423*

Comment: It really worries me to see this sort of ratoms-all-over-the-place architecture.  You'll get away with it at small scale, but as your application gets bigger it will become problematic.  You are going to hurt yourself.  Use something like re-frame (warning: I am the author) or invent your own variation of it.

Comment: Mike, I already had a look at re-frame and we like it (also the documentation for reagent and re-frame), but I don't think it is necessary for us now. We have been developing on a single immutable app state in javascript for over a year, quite a big application and we had no issues, and my guys are pretty used to that way of working. The application has basically only 2 atoms - app-state and history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(catch :default e
  (swap! errors conj e))))
```

because the string thrown is not an object, but a string!